# add tooltip to each drag and drop block

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Here is a drag and drop blocks code we have:

```js
$(function(e) {
  function enableEdit(e) {
    var $this = $(e.target);
    $this.closest(".ui-sortable").enableSelection();
    var cnt = $this.text();
    $this.off("dblclick")
      .addClass("editing");
    var inp = $("<input>", {
      val: cnt
    }).css({
      width: "60px",
      marginTop: "-10px"
    });
    $this.html(inp);
    $this.find("input").focus();
  }

  function prepareEdits(o) {
    o.dblclick(enableEdit);
    $(document).click(clickOff);
    $(".sortit").on("keyup", ".editing > input", function(e) {
      if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(document).click();
      }
    });
  }

  function disableEdit(o) {
    o.closest(".ui-sortable").disableSelection();
    o.removeClass("editing");
    prepareEdits(o);
  }

  function clickOff(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("editing") || $(e.target).parent().hasClass("editing")) {
      return;
    }
    var $this = $(".editing");
    var cnt = $this.find("input").val();
    $this.html("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span>" + cnt);
    disableEdit($this);
  }

  prepareEdits($('.ui-state-default'));

  $(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable" //use this to connect with other uls
  });
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();

  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    const positions = [];
    var count = 0;
    //get length of all sortable class
    var length = $(".sortable").length;
    //chck if count is less then length
    while (count < length) {
      //create empty arry
      data = []
      //loop thorugh uls .. li 
      $("ul:eq(" + count + ") li").each(function(index, element) {
        data.push($(this).text()) //push data in array
      });
      positions.push(data) //push datas in outer array
      count++; //increment
    }
    console.log(positions)
  });

});
```

```css
.sortit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sortable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  user-select: text;
  font-size: 2vw;
  height: 18px;
  background: gainsboro;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sortable li.editing {
  background-color: CadetBlue;
  color: AntiqueWhite;
}

.sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>Sort listing using drag & drop</h1>
<div class="sortit">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="8"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="9"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="10"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 10</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="11"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="12"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 12</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="13"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 13</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="14"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 14</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Drag and drop list to reposition...</p>
<button id="btn">Get positions and save them into an array of arrays</button>
<div class="show"></div>
```

I want to add one more functionality but I can't find a proper solution without a hand.

let's say the user reorders the blocks as he/she wants like below, I want him to be able to see a  a tooltip or just a console log added to each block which shows a number representing the order of the blocks (the number I have showed in the image below):

[image]

Note that user can reorder the blocks again and the number we get with updated blocks should be updated so we cannot simply give an id to each block and get back that id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your btn click event, you loop through all of the items to "export" them - at the same time (or recreate this loop on drop) you can apply an increasing position value:

```
var count = 0;
var pos = 1;
var length = $(".sortable").length;
while (count < length) {
  //loop thorugh uls .. li 
  $("ul:eq(" + count + ") li").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).prop("title", pos++);
  });
  count++;
}
```

Updated snippet, drag+drop then click the button to update tooltips

```js
$(function(e) {
  function enableEdit(e) {
    var $this = $(e.target);
    $this.closest(".ui-sortable").enableSelection();
    var cnt = $this.text();
    $this.off("dblclick")
      .addClass("editing");
    var inp = $("<input>", {
      val: cnt
    }).css({
      width: "60px",
      marginTop: "-10px"
    });
    $this.html(inp);
    $this.find("input").focus();
  }

  function prepareEdits(o) {
    o.dblclick(enableEdit);
    $(document).click(clickOff);
    $(".sortit").on("keyup", ".editing > input", function(e) {
      if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(document).click();
      }
    });
  }

  function disableEdit(o) {
    o.closest(".ui-sortable").disableSelection();
    o.removeClass("editing");
    prepareEdits(o);
  }

  function clickOff(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("editing") || $(e.target).parent().hasClass("editing")) {
      return;
    }
    var $this = $(".editing");
    var cnt = $this.find("input").val();
    $this.html("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span>" + cnt);
    disableEdit($this);
  }

  prepareEdits($('.ui-state-default'));

  $(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable" //use this to connect with other uls
  });
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();

  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    const positions = [];
    var count = 0;
    var pos = 1;
    //get length of all sortable class
    var length = $(".sortable").length;
    //chck if count is less then length
    while (count < length) {
      //create empty arry
      data = []
      //loop thorugh uls .. li 
      $("ul:eq(" + count + ") li").each(function(index, element) {
        data.push($(this).text()) //push data in array
        $(this).prop("title", pos++);
      });
      positions.push(data) //push datas in outer array
      count++; //increment
    }
    console.log(positions)
  });

});
```

```css
.sortit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sortable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  user-select: text;
  font-size: 2vw;
  height: 18px;
  background: gainsboro;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sortable li.editing {
  background-color: CadetBlue;
  color: AntiqueWhite;
}

.sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>Sort listing using drag & drop</h1>
<div class="sortit">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="8"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="9"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="10"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 10</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="11"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="12"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 12</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="13"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 13</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="14"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 14</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Drag and drop list to reposition...</p>
<button id="btn">Get positions and save them into an array of arrays</button>
<div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks WOW...Please correct me : you just added these two lines: `var pos = 1;` and `$(this).prop("title", pos++);` or there are other changes?

Comment: Yes, added to your existing code.  You can pull that part out and apply to the drop event as well if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to communicate back the position to the user you can use a [CSS counter](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp) I've set it to increment on each `<li>` within the `.sortit` div and it will update automatically after the order of the blocks have changed.

So it is just some extra CSS. The rest of your code stays the same.

#### CSS

```
.sortit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  counter-reset: item;
}

.sortit li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: "Position " counter(item);
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: floralwhite;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

#### Full code snippet

```js
$(function(e) {
  function enableEdit(e) {
    var $this = $(e.target);
    $this.closest(".ui-sortable").enableSelection();
    var cnt = $this.text();
    $this.off("dblclick")
      .addClass("editing");
    var inp = $("<input>", {
      val: cnt
    }).css({
      width: "60px",
      marginTop: "-10px"
    });
    $this.html(inp);
    $this.find("input").focus();
  }

  function prepareEdits(o) {
    o.dblclick(enableEdit);
    $(document).click(clickOff);
    $(".sortit").on("keyup", ".editing > input", function(e) {
      if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(document).click();
      }
    });
  }

  function disableEdit(o) {
    o.closest(".ui-sortable").disableSelection();
    o.removeClass("editing");
    prepareEdits(o);
  }

  function clickOff(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("editing") || $(e.target).parent().hasClass("editing")) {
      return;
    }
    var $this = $(".editing");
    var cnt = $this.find("input").val();
    $this.html("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span>" + cnt);
    disableEdit($this);
  }

  prepareEdits($('.ui-state-default'));

  $(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable" //use this to connect with other uls
  });
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();

  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    const positions = [];
    var count = 0;
    //get length of all sortable class
    var length = $(".sortable").length;
    //chck if count is less then length
    while (count < length) {
      //create empty arry
      data = []
      //loop thorugh uls .. li 
      $("ul:eq(" + count + ") li").each(function(index, element) {
        data.push($(this).text()) //push data in array
      });
      positions.push(data) //push datas in outer array
      count++; //increment
    }
    console.log(positions)
  });

});
```

```css
.sortit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  counter-reset: item;
}

.sortit li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: "Position " counter(item);
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: floralwhite;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sortable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
}

.sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  user-select: text;
  font-size: 2vw;
  height: auto;
  background: gainsboro;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sortable li.editing {
  background-color: CadetBlue;
  color: AntiqueWhite;
}

.sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h1>Sort listing using drag & drop</h1>
<div class="sortit">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="8"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="9"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="10"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 10</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="11"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="12"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 12</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="13"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 13</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="14"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 14</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Drag and drop list to reposition...</p>
<button id="btn">Get positions and save them into an array of arrays</button>
<div class="show"></div>
```